# IBM API Management Service - How to bind a SSL profile to a Proxy API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, ibm-api-management

I have some APIs on my laptop. They are visible on the internet through secure gateway service.

The secure gateway destination is configured with TLS mutual authentication option. So APIs require TLS mutual authentication.

I would like to add those APIs to API Management.

I could not bind a SSL profile on Proxy tab, but I could bind a SSL profile to an HTTP GET operation on Implementation tab.

Does this mean I have to implement an assembly operation to bind a SSL profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Proxy" tab is meant as a "simple" get you going proxy setup. For more advanced "proxies", you should use an "Assembly" implementation with a "Proxy" policy. On the settings for the Proxy policy you can specify an SSL profile.